# Generate RSA to existent validation

Tags: c#, rsa, sha1

I need to generate a new license file fro a customer.
The system work with a RSA key validation where the publickey is in DB and there is a license.lic file with informations like domain, expire date and the last field is another key.

```
license file: 87b6fe89-c0b6-431d-96ad-449d055755eb#2020/11/08#True#True#True#True#True#True#True#True#True#True#False#True#True#True#True#True#http://sitesample.com,http://www.sitesample.com,http://localhost#SiIQ6U50tHrfuZD8yCTDq1VJ3teSYnCEDzdJ4RpsLOBMEUcvgn5WiphHFKwYDrKlGUfgnO2iyMRVf2pkFY0c0yuMklBfd31TGlEdZ1uMEFG+WTY42+K5UZzxEs8Y16sNSXKok5fRtF3WRAqckkT3Xkm893zJcr+vcXqdk6rK3r4=

DB row: <RSAKeyValue>Modulus>s0TTPk5n7yS+7gp7VDNZCOnAPYbb24sLGmIviZpayS5aCpxsPKR/R53gbNMII3vBUXyLXg4V99rPffvmTuJuAxw4OPFcGc4cF5w2wiPd7uSCkkjuY9wbyK8YeF4Ge18Zmsl/1ewFM5nVS95XYKQJNR5SY1PAyRVwIfrdtBWTqWk=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
```

The validation code is:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Concat(new string[]
                {
                    values[0],
                    "#",
                    values[1],
                    "#",
                    values[2],
                    "#",
                    values[3],
                    "#",
                    values[4],
                    "#",
                    values[5],
                    "#",
                    values[6],
                    "#",
                    values[7],
                    "#",
                    values[8],
                    "#",
                    values[9],
                    "#",
                    values[10],
                    "#",
                    values[11],
                    "#",
                    values[12],
                    "#",
                    values[13],
                    "#",
                    values[14],
                    "#",
                    values[15],
                    "#",
                    values[16],
                    "#",
                    values[17],
                    "#",
                    values[18],
                    "#"
                }));
                SHA1Managed sHA1Managed = new SHA1Managed();
                byte[] rgbHash = sHA1Managed.ComputeHash(bytes);
                RSACryptoServiceProvider rSACryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                rSACryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(registration.public_key);
                byte[] rgbSignature = Convert.FromBase64String(values[19]);
                bool flag = rSACryptoServiceProvider.VerifyHash(rgbHash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), rgbSignature);
                return flag;
```

This validation works fine but I need to insert a new domain on license file so I must generate new keys.

I wouldn't change the validation code because it is on live and I only have the dll file (got this code using ILSpy) so the best for me is create a new license file and an insert in database.

I downloaded these samples of internet and tried use the keys generated but the validation always return false, I think the SHA1 in my code can be the problem.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10877/Public-Key-RSA-Encryption-in-C-NET
and 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38739/RSA-Private-Key-Encryption

Could someone give me a hand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I created a new console application using this code and works fine with my validation.
[Using the RSACryptoServiceProvider to sign a hash from a server and then verifying the hash from client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373373/using-the-rsacryptoserviceprovider-to-sign-a-hash-from-a-server-and-then-verifyi)

```
public string EncryptString( string inputString, int dwKeySize, string xmlString )
{
        string name = inputString;
        FileStream fs = File.Create(@"license.lic");
        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
        StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(fs);
        write.Write(name + "\r\n");
        string pkey = RSA.ToXmlString(false);
        write.Write(pkey + "\r\n");
        SHA1Managed Sha = new SHA1Managed();
        byte[] hashed = Sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(name));
        byte[] signature = RSA.SignHash(hashed, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"));
        write.Write(Convert.ToBase64String(signature));

        write.Close();
        fs.Close();

        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashed);    
    }

    public string DecryptString( string inputString, int dwKeySize, string xmlString )
    {
        FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(@"license.lic", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fsSource);

        string name = reader.ReadLine();
        string pkey = reader.ReadLine();
        string signed = reader.ReadLine();

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);

        SHA1Managed sHA1Managed = new SHA1Managed();
        byte[] rgbHash = sHA1Managed.ComputeHash(bytes);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rSACryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rSACryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(pkey);
        byte[] rgbSignature = Convert.FromBase64String(signed);
        bool flag = rSACryptoServiceProvider.VerifyHash(rgbHash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), rgbSignature);

        return flag.ToString();
}
```